# Need to make by new round new player turn to first move

Tags: javascript, playing-cards

I try to make card game on Javascript, but I to make by every new round new players turn to move:

- 1 round - player 1 started first move;
- 2 round - player 2;
- 3 round -    player 3;
- 4 - player 4;
- 5 - player 1 again , etc till the games end

  Thank You!

Comment: Could you post code that you already have?

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 1):

What about `playerTurn = (++playerTurn % 5) + 1`